# Laravel 8: Pagination returned int value in when clicking next page

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-pagination

In the table, we implemented the pagination and it is working properly. We customize the pagination name but when I click the next page it gives me an error "***Invalid Foreach / Call to a member function links() on int***"

When I tried to die dump it gives me 1 (for example I clicked the page 2). I changed the default value of $pageNumber in Builder file to null because I want it to be dynamic.

**Builder**

```
//original code
public function paginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null)

//edited 
public function paginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = null, $page = null)
```

**Controller**

```
$sales                                  = Sale::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
                                                ->whereBetween('date_delivered', [$this->start_date, $this->end_date])
                                                ->where('level_id',4)
                                                ->search(trim($this->search))
                                                ->orderBy($this->column, $this->order)
                                                ->paginate($this->size,['*'],'sales');
```

Question: Why when I clicked the any page it returned an int value?

Comment: what do you mean by this ``I changed the default value of $pageNumber in Builder file to null because I want it to be dynamic.`` ?

Comment: As far as I understand, the pageNumber is hard coded to "page". I changed it to null to make it dynamic.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to make changes in the ORIGINAL code i.e `` $pageName = null``. Keep it intact and still you can pass ``'sales'`` as the key name instead of default ``page``

Comment: But if I didn't change it, it still 'page' even though I already renamed it.

Comment: It should work, you might be making mistake somewhere else. Are you caching the response?